GLFW window hint errors using nanogui example code
I'm trying to implement one example application for nanogui as a baseline for my application. (I use the "updated" nanogui, that has some format changes compared to the documentation).
This is the (barely modified) example code:
// includes, system
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

// includes OpenGL
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// includes GUI
#include <nanogui/nanogui.h>

using namespace nanogui;

const unsigned int window_width = 1920;
const unsigned int window_height = 1080;

const char application_name[] = "Molecular Surfaces";



enum test_enum
{
  Item1 = 0,
  Item2,
  Item3
};

bool bvar = true;
int ivar = 12345678;
double dvar = 3.1415926;
float fvar = (float)dvar;
std::string strval = "A string";
test_enum enumval = Item2;
Color colval(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 1.f);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  nanogui::init();

    Screen *screen = nullptr;

    screen = new Screen({window_width, window_height}, application_name);
   
    bool enabled = true;
    FormHelper *gui = new FormHelper(screen);
    ref<Window> window = gui->add_window(Vector2i(10, 10), "Form helper example");
    gui->add_group("Basic types");
    gui->add_variable("bool", bvar);
    gui->add_variable("string", strval);

    gui->add_group("Validating fields");
    gui->add_variable("int", ivar)->set_spinnable(true);
    gui->add_variable("float", fvar);
    gui->add_variable("double", dvar)->set_spinnable(true);

    gui->add_group("Complex types");
    gui->add_variable("Enumeration", enumval, enabled)
        ->set_items({"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"});
    gui->add_variable("Color", colval)
        ->set_final_callback([](const Color &c)
                             { std::cout << "ColorPicker Final Callback: ["
                                         << c.r() << ", "
                                         << c.g() << ", "
                                         << c.b() << ", "
                                         << c.w() << "]" << std::endl; });

    gui->add_group("Other widgets");
    gui->add_button("A button", []()
                    { std::cout << "Button pressed." << std::endl; });

    screen->set_visible(true);
    screen->perform_layout();
    window->center();
    
    nanogui::mainloop();
    //while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(screen->glfw_window()))
    //{
    //glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    //screen->draw_contents();
    //screen->draw_widgets();
    // glfwSwapBuffers(screen->glfw_window());
    //glfwPollEvents();
    //}
  }
  nanogui::shutdown();
  return 0;
}


Using the nanogui mainloop the program runs without errors. But when I want to create my own main loop (commented code parts below the nanogui mainloop) I get the error:
GLFW error 65539: Invalid window hint 0x00021011

With prints I narrowed down the location of the error to the creation of the nanogui screen. Even with the error the GUI is shown and interactable. Using the nanogui mainloop doesnt work for me, because I need to draw a background texture at some point (that changes every frame).
I'm scared that my error is with the setup of nanogui; I managed to do that only with a lot of trial and error. For context, here is my CMakeLists.txt file (that loads all the necessary stuff I need for the per frame texture changes):
####################################################################
### project setup ##################################################
####################################################################
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

# Define project and executable name
set(PROJECT_NAME MolecularSurfaces)
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME Surfaces)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)


# Make sure binary directory is not the same as source directory
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(
    FATAL_ERROR
      "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there."
  )
endif()


# enable unit testing via "make test" once the code has been compiled.
include(CTest)

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)


# # Define common paths
set(DEP_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep)
set(GLAD_INSTALL_DIR ${DEP_DIR}/glad/install)
set(GLFW_INSTALL_DIR ${DEP_DIR}/glfw/install)
set(GLM_INSTALL_DIR ${DEP_DIR}/glm/install)
set(NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/nanogui-install)

####################################################################
### external projects ##############################################
####################################################################
# Add OpenGL, glfw, glad, glm and nanogui as external project
include(ExternalProject)

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS /NODEFAULTLIB:\"libcmt.lib\")

set(libGLFW glfw)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLFW}
PREFIX          ${DEP_DIR}/${libGLFW}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
GIT_TAG         3.4.1
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}
                -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLAD glad)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLAD}
PREFIX          ${DEP_DIR}/${libGLAD}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLM glm)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLM}
    PREFIX ${DEP_DIR}/${libGLM}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 # Do not update the external project if it is already downloaded
    CMAKE_ARGS  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
    )

# Define the options to pass to NanoGUI's CMake build
set(NANOGUI_CMAKE_ARGS
    "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}"
    "-DNANOGUI_BUILD_SHARED=OFF"  # You can adjust these options based on your needs
    "-DNANOGUI_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF"
    "-DNANOGUI_BUILD_PYTHON=OFF"
    "-DNANOGUI_BUILD_GLFW=ON"
)

# Download and build NanoGUI as an external project
ExternalProject_Add(
    NanoGUI
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/nanogui.git
    GIT_TAG master  # Specify the version or commit hash if needed
    CMAKE_ARGS ${NANOGUI_CMAKE_ARGS}
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1  # Disable automatic updates
    INSTALL_DIR ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}
)

# SETUP GLFW
add_library(GLFW_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glfw3.lib)
set_property(TARGET GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})

# SETUP GLAD
add_library(GLAD_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glad.lib)
set_property(TARGET GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR})

####################################################################
### project files ##################################################
####################################################################

# list project files
# TODO when finishing project: list files explicitly as GLOB is not recommended
file(GLOB_RECURSE app CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/*.cu")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.cuh")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c")


# Create a single .lib file containing our compiled objects, and the compiled objects of all other dependencies
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${app} ${headers} ${sources})


# Add all include file paths
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app
)

# copy shaders
add_custom_target(copy_shaders ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/shaders
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/shaders
    COMMENT "Copying shaders into binary directory")

  # Specify the order in which libs depend on each other
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libGLFW} ${libGLAD} copy_shaders)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GLAD_LIBRARY GLFW_LIBRARY)

####################################################################
### cuda configurations ############################################
####################################################################
# Request that particles be built with -std=c++17
# As this is a public compile feature anything that links to
# particles will also build with -std=c++17
# TODO: test rdc (shouldnt be required while header only)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:
                        # --generate-line-info
                        --device-debug
                        --use_fast_math
                        # --relocatable-device-code=true
                        >)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-G>)


# Set CUDA architecture
# default value: 75 to match testing system with nvidia 2080 card
# TODO variable with architecture/set by user
if(NOT DEFINED ${CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES})
  set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75 CACHE STRING "CUDA architectures" FORCE)
endif()
message(STATUS "CUDA architectures set to ${CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES}")

# We need to explicitly state that we need all CUDA files in the
# particle library to be built with -dc as the member functions
# could be called by other libraries and executables
set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
                       PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
                       CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON
                       )



# add executable
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}  app/main.cu)

target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_C_DIR}
)

set_property(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
             PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
             CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON
             )
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${NANOGUI_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/nanogui.lib)

